# Float image to the left and center text vertically next to the image

Tags: css

So I've been struggling with this problem for a while and I can't find a good solution.

I want a thumbnail image to the left inside the div container and text next to the image BUT centered vertically.

Currently code looks like that:

```
.img-thumbnail{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
}

.text{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And the effect is like this:
http://prntscr.com/ff9mhi

However, if I remove float:left from the image they are both centered vertically inside their div, but that's not what im looking for. I need the image to be floated to the left, because it's gonna be smaller and the text is going to be long

Comment: Try using flex, with `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't float the image, and only use `vertical-align` on the image.

```css
.img-thumbnail{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.text{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    text
  </div>
</header>
```

You could also make the parent `display: flex; align-items: center;` to do the same thing with less code and have more options over positioning. I would recommend using this, but wanted to provide a solution with your original code, too, since you were close.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    text
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, will definitely use your second code. I also finally found my mistake, somehow I completely forgot that I set "text-align: center" on the whole body and it was ruining everything I tried.